# Как получить био профиля в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу своего бота модератора для телеграма на python через aiogram. Он прекрасно умеет хендлить сообщения и проверять их на запрещенные слова. А еще он умеет проверять отредактированные сообщения через @dp.edited_message_handler(). Можно ли как-то заставить его проверять описание профиля (био) отправителя? Чтобы если там окажется ссылка, сообщение удалялось без разбора.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_info = await bot.get_chat(тут id пользователя)  # тут информация о профиле
print(user_info.bio)  # тут био
```